# gdal_retile.py and gdal_translate Requirements

Tags: gdal

I basically need to use two GDAL utilities: gdal_retile.py and gdal_translate, on a Solaris 9 machine. I have tried compiling GDAL from sources, but this seems not to be working. So, since I have python on my server machine, can I just use the utilities without compiling gdal or these utilities depend on GDAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you'll need to make a GDAL build, or find a build for Solaris. The GDAL py utilities require Python bindings or they won't work (which I'm guessing you discovered by now).

Perhaps I should be slapped for this but.. could you just handle these tasks on a different computer? Getting them going on either Windows or linux is trivial.

Otherwise, I'd suggest hitting up the gdal-dev mailing list to request some assistance getting your Solaris build going. Have you seen this [page of Solaris build tips](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/SolarisNotes)? It seems the authority on this topic is Christian Schaffer.

Comment: Thanks...I actually had to do a rebuild as you suggested and everything worked fine.